# Check for which array in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a navigation menu where submenu link are `href="?p=1a"`. I solved the problem by hardcoding a lot of `if` statements, but it could be solved with like 5 lines of code by doing this with arrays. I dont know how to check which array it should display content from depnding on what `?p` is equal to in url bar. I have started but dont know how to procced.

```
$database= array(
    '1a' => array ('data1','data2','data,3')
    '1b' => array ('data4','data5','data,6')
    '1c' => array ('data7','data8','data,9')
    '1d' => array ('data10','data11','data,12'));

foreach($database as key=> $data){

    $page_id=$_GET['p'];
    if($data==$page_id){

        $get_choice=mysql_query("SELECT FROM choice where $data='1'") or die();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_choice){
            $choice_id=$row['id'];
        }
        echo $choice_id;
        $choice_id="";
    }
}
```

where `?p` is equal to deside which array it should choose with the following data elements.

**Edit**
 data1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc etc is collumns in a my database that is either 1 or 0 depending on what users have checked in checkboxes and if it they checked data1 it will recive 1 and it will display content in certain div tags, when someone clicks a sublink in nav menu it will only display data1, data2, data3,data4, depending on what link they clicked.

Comment: `choice_id` doesn't have a `$` preceding it on the last line, so isn't seen as a variable

Comment: i corrected the typing misstake, but that wasent the problem to slove i was looking for.

Comment: I know that's not an answer to your question, that's why it was mentioned in 'comments' and not in 'answers' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, are you trying to send multiple parameters as array then, you may use html same name element to send array of params.

Then you would just need to access the `$_GET[$_GET['p']][0 .. 10]`
 params. I guess that is what you are looking for. So you can build you query easily.

For same name for multiple elements:
`<input type=text name=1a[] />  #data0
<input type=text name=1a[] />  #data1
<input type=text name=1a[] />  #data2`
`

Comment: this is kinda the way i do it but instead i asign a value to data1,2,3,4 that can be either 1 or 0 depending on what checkbox they checked.